Calculate $I(\alpha)=\int_0^\pi \frac{x}{1+\sin(x)\cos(\alpha)}dx$
I have tried to derive it 1 and 2 times but I do not see any relation to the original $I(\alpha)$, is there any breakthrough that I am missing?

Differentiating under the integral sign here would be unecessary, the integral is solvable by elementary means. First, a phase shift $x \to \pi - x$:
\begin{align}
I(\alpha) = \int_0^{\pi} \frac{\pi - x}{1 + \sin x \cos \alpha}dx
\end{align}
Adding this to the original integral yeilds:
\begin{align}
I(\alpha) = \frac 12 \int_0^{\pi} \frac{\pi}{1 + \sin x \cos \alpha} dx
\end{align}
The integrand is symmetric about $\pi/2$ which gives us:
\begin{align}
I(\alpha) = \pi \int_0^{\frac{\pi}2} \frac{1}{1 + \sin x \cos \alpha} dx
\end{align}
Now for the popular Weierstrass substition, $\tan \left (\frac x2 \right ) \to x$:
\begin{align}
I(\alpha) = 2\pi \int_0^{1} \frac{1}{x^2 + 2x\cos\alpha + 1}dx
\end{align}
The procedure henceforth is simple:
\begin{align}
I(\alpha) = 2\pi \int_0^{1} \frac{1}{(x + \cos \alpha )^2 + \sin^2 \alpha}dx
\end{align}
This is recognizable as a parametric arctangent integral:
\begin{align}
I(\alpha) = \frac{2\pi}{\sin \alpha} \left ( \tan^{-1}(\csc \alpha + \cot \alpha) - \tan^{-1}(\cot \alpha) \right )
\end{align}
I hope this helped you!

You can simplify the difference of two arctangents.

Since @NEON gave the solution, let us try another way.
Using Euler's representation of the the sine function, let $x=-i\log(t)$
$$\int \frac{x}{1+\sin(x)\cos(\alpha)}dx=2 \int \frac {\log(t) } {i  \cos (\alpha )\,t^2-2 t-i \cos (\alpha)}\,dt$$ The denominator write
$$i  \cos (\alpha ) (t-a)(t-b)$$ with
$$a=-i \, \frac{\cos \left(\frac{\alpha }{2}\right)-\sin
   \left(\frac{\alpha }{2}\right)}{\sin
   \left(\frac{\alpha }{2}\right)+\cos
   \left(\frac{\alpha }{2}\right)}\qquad \text{and}\qquad b=-i\, \frac{\sin \left(\frac{\alpha }{2}\right)+\cos
   \left(\frac{\alpha }{2}\right)}{\cos
   \left(\frac{\alpha }{2}\right)-\sin
   \left(\frac{\alpha }{2}\right)}$$
Using partial fraction decomposition, the integrand is
$$i\,\frac{2 \sec (\alpha )}{a-b}\Bigg(\frac{\log(t)}{t-b}-\frac{\log(t)}{t-a}   \Bigg)$$ and we face two integrals of the family
$$\int \frac{\log(t)}{t-c}\,dt=\text{Li}_2\left(\frac{t}{c}\right)+\log (t)\, \log
   \left(1-\frac{t}{c}\right)$$
With all the above, we have the explicit result for
$$J(\alpha,z)=\int_0^z \frac{x}{1+\sin(x)\cos(\alpha)}dx$$
Replace $(a,b,t)$ by their definitions and use the bounds to obtain $I(\alpha)$.
Notice that, depending on the quadrant, @NEON result can extremely simplify.
